# How and when do principal homogeneous spaces form a group?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Here's what I understand:

- Given a group $G$, a principal homogeneous space for $G$ consists of a set $X$ together with a free and transitive action of $G$ on $X$. Free in this context means that for all $x \in X$, the function $g \mapsto gx$ is injective. Transitive means that the aforementioned function is surjective.
- Principal homogeneous spaces for $G$ form a group, at least under certain assumptions. In algebraic geometry this is called [Weil–Châtelet group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil%E2%80%93Ch%C3%A2telet_group).

Perhaps it's obvious, but I can't see how such a group could be defined, and finding an elementary account of such things has proved difficult.

> **Question.**
>
> - How is this group defined?
> - What's the minimum assumptions on (and/or structure on $G$) necessary for this group to be defined?

Comment: At least in situation of algebraic groups, isomorphism classes of homogeneous spaces are parameterized by a certain Galois cohomology, which is necessarily an abelian group. For general (nonalgebraic) groups, I do not know exactly what happens, but I would guess that if your collection of principal homogeneous spaces were classified by a group object, you would get what you want. For topological groups, you will want to look up classifying spaces and see what you can get from there.